# Facebook is unable to scrape some pages

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having some trouble tracking down the source of an issue with Facebook sharing. A particular example URL is http://kimbeach.com/programs/nolimits/.

The [Facebook Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fkimbeach.com%2Fprograms%2Fnolimits%2F) reports that it '**Could not resolve the hostname into a valid IP address.**'

I can't seem to figure out why it has trouble with this one URL (along with some seemingly random blog posts) when it happily parses an almost identical page of the same nature (using the same WordPress template) – http://kimbeach.com/programs/noexcuses/.

Does anybody know how I go about tracking down and fixing this problem? I've reported the issue with Facebook, but I assume they don't repond to those messages.

Comment: Where did you report it to Facebook? I just forced a new scrape on that URL from the debugger and it seems to be working correctly.

Comment: @The1Fitz, I reported it via the **Report a problem** link in the dropdown at the top right of the Facebook toolbar. Strange that it is now able to crawl the page – forcing the scrape did nothing when I was trying it.  

I don't understand why the FB crawler struggles to reach certain pages/posts, and the debugger they provide is only useful to a point. They need to provide info as to why the crawler couldn't reach the page.